# How to import an existing Linux WSL machine to use with podman desktop?

Tags: linux, windows, containers, wsl-2, podman

Currently you can run `podman machine init`, which will download Fedora CoreOS and install a new WSL distro.

But is it possible to install a custom WSL distro (e.g., Debian), install podman on it and finally add it to the podman installed on windows so it shows when I run `podman machine list`? Or is it limited and I can only use CoreOS as a machine?

I know I can start the tcp service with `podman system service start -t 0 tcp://localhost:8888` and then add it from Windows with `podman system connection add user tcp://localhost:8888`, but that's not what I want.

Comment: Not exactly what you want to do, but: 
you can create a machine via `podman machine init`, edit it via `wsl -d podman-machine-name`, export and import it via `podman machine init --image-path machine.tar machine-name`.

resource: https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-machine-init.1.html